# Spring Roo. How to customize input and table row?

Tags: spring-roo

I have 2 simple questions related to Spring Roo UI part.

Q.1:
How can I change default input size of field:input?

Q.2:
`<table:column property="user" ..>`  shows all user fields in column. How tell it to show only firtName and lastName fields?

Thank you

Comment: Q2 was solved (Thanks Kapil).  Q1 is still problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to change ApplicationConversionFactory Class and change the method related to your class

For example

```
public Converter<WindFarm, String> getSomeClassToStringConverter() {
        return new org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<com.domain.someClass, java.lang.String>() {
            public String convert(SomeClass someClass) {
                return new StringBuilder().append(someClass.getName()).toString();
            }
        };
    }
```

You can change the String builder to append only the field required by  you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm. In my case name of the class is ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean.